# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" - django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying docker-compose an app with django and postgres using docker-compose but I get an error with the "NAME"

Here is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication
> failed for user "postgres"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you connect manually to your postgres database with this password?

Comment: @Yaroslav thanks man, your comment made me think in a different angle and I managed to fix it! Baaah, that was alot of work. I addd my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things were wrong in my code.
After 6 hours of debugging.

First I changed all my docker-compose.yml to

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

In my settings.py I did:

```
import environ
import os

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

# Set the project base directory
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# False if not in os.environ because of casting above
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Raises Django's ImproperlyConfigured
# exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# Parse database connection url strings
# like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises
    # ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    #
    # The db() method is an alias for db_url().
    'default': env.db(),


}
```

I then created the .env

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=xxx
DATABASE_URL=psql://postgres:123@db:5432/postgres
```

I then entered into docker using

```
docker ps -a

docker exec -it <container_id> bash

psql postgres postgres

\password postgres

123
123
```

I then migrated my database

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations
docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate
```