# Django Postgres docker-compose connection error mainly failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user foobar ERROR: 2

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a django microservice with postgres database. and I have a problem which I cant solve it for few days. this question contains serveral errors. so you may ignore them and answer last error which is about access `psql shell` (`port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" Error` section) or ignore all and answer the main question of how to have a `docker-compose` with `django` and `postgres` containers.

the `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.4-alpine
    container_name: redis
  # rabbit
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: "rabbitmq:3.10.7-alpine"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:5.0.10
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  # Main Database Postgres
  main_postgres_ser:
    image: postgres:14.4-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB= postgres # NAME
      - POSTGRES_USER= postgres # USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= postgrespass # PASSWORD
    container_name: postgres_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      # - 8000:8000 # HTTP port
      - 5432:5432 # DB port
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
  # Main Django Application
  main_django_ser:
    build:
      context: . #/main_ms
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_main_ms
    container_name: main_django
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/main_ms
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    depends_on:
      - main_postgres_ser
      - rabbit
    links:
      - main_postgres_ser:main_postgres_ser
networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  main_postgres_ser:
    driver: local
```

the Dockerfile for django service looks like:

```
FROM python:3.10.6-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo
WORKDIR /main_ms
COPY requirements.txt ./main_ms/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r ./main_ms/requirements.txt
```

and in `settings.py` in `DATABASES` I have

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'default':'psql://postgres:postgrespass@postgres:5432/postgres',
        # 'default':'postgres://postgres:postgrespass@postgres:5432/postgres',
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME' : 'postgres',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD' : 'postgrespass',
        # HOST should be as postgres service name
        'HOST' : 'main_postgres_ser',
        'PORT' : '5432',
         }}
```

as I know the [HOST should be as postgres service name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67637906/11692124)(here `main_postgres_ser`) because `DNS name` will be the same.

###### password authentication failed for user Error

so I built docker-compose then initialized the django project, ran docker-compose up and inside the django container made migrations but when I do `python manage.py migrate` I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

so with [just keeping the default in `DATABASES` in `settings.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392078/11692124) (`'default':'postgres://postgres:postgrespass@main_postgres_ser:5432/postgres',`) with pattern of `'default':'postgres://postgres:pass@host:port/dbname',`.

thus I got everything commented in `DATABASES` (except `default` and `ENGINE`) and got rid of last error. note that I had to keep `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',` (not to get another error) in `DATABASES`.

###### Please supply the NAME or OPTIONS['service'] Error

but then again I received `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME or OPTIONS['service'] value.` note I also can access `http://localhost:8000/` on `browser` and there I had django's yellow debug page.

###### connections on Unix domain socket PGSQL.5432 Error

but when I uncomment `'NAME' : 'postgres',` in `DATABASES` I got `connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` error I have not access to `http://localhost:8000/` in the `browser` again.

###### no password supplied Error

so I uncommented `HOST` in `DATABASES` and got `django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

###### again `password authentication failed for user` Error

so I uncommented `PASSWORD` and got `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"` which is same as `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` (in the case of uncommenting `'USER'='postgres'`) so I'm again at the first step!!!

inside the django container I tried to [CREATE USER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43061363/11692124) with `CREATE USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgrespass';` or `postgres=# CREATE USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgrespass';` but I got `CREATE: not found`I again tried it in `postgres container` and got same result.

I also tried last solution by adding `local   all         postgres                          peer` to `pg_hba.conf` still didnt work.

###### unrecognized service Error

`sudo -u root postgresql psql` resulted `sudo: postgresql: command not found` or `sudo service postgresql start` resulted `postgresql: unrecognized service`

###### psql: error: connection PGSQL.5432 Error

then I tried to [access to psql shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753979/11692124) with `docker exec -it -u postgres postgres_container psql` which I received the `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

###### port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" Error

in order to try [`CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'pass';`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43061363/11692124) I want to access `psql shell` with `docker-compose run --rm main_postgres_ser psql -h main_postgres_ser -U postgres -d postgres` things seems to fine and working because it pops up enter password input but when I enter the `postgrespass` which is my password for `postgres` user I get `port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" ERROR: 2` Error in the `postgres container` and in the terminal that `docker-compose` is up I get `DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.`.

I also specified `user: postgres` in `postgres docker-compose` [like this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67865761/11692124) and didnt change any thing.

##### questions

so why I get error even I put my password for `postgres` user?

or how can I make a `docker-compose` for `django` and `postgres`??

Comment: Is there really an space after the assignment sign in your docker compose file for PostgreSQL environment variables?

Comment: Pop a shell in the db container, and look in the db log file for a (possibly) more detailed error message.

Comment: @hedayat I remove space after in `- POSTGRES_DB= postgres` to - `POSTGRES_DB=postgres` and it didnt solve the problem. also tried it with `- "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"` which I have seen in some docker-compose files also didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @hedayat I realized that the spaces after `=` for `environment variables` in docker-compose are not the cause and the main cause was the in between step of creating django folders(project and the apps) the `data\db` gets created and it doesn't let the authentication happen. so by `deleting data\db` I was able to do `migrate` the database.

Comment: in my case it was the final answer. but someone please comments on should I keep the question open or I should make it final answer?

Comment: Im facing a similar issue. Cant figure out. Could you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767159/django-db-utils-operationalerror-connection-to-server-failed-fatal-password-a